# is my if statement doing what i think its doing?

Tags: parse-platform

Here I have tis function that is querying data and returning it to me and im putting that data in to html elements to make a post.my if statement at the bottom is where im having a bit of problem i trying to only apply my comment window once to the new clones once they have been pushed over to the new div called story board, i believe im telling my if statement that if the class already exists in that new clone then do nothing else apply it there.. to seee what i am talking about...here is my test domain...http://subdomain.jason-c.com/
sign in is "kio" pass is the same and when you hit publish on the stories, everytime a nw one hits it will apply comment box to a post in the storyboard window that already has a comment text area. what am i doing wrong.

```
function publishWindowHandler(){

var query = new Parse.Query('Post');
console.log(currentUser); 
query.equalTo("User", currentUser);
query.include("User");
query.descending("createdAt")
console.log(user.get('username'));

query.find({
success:function(results){
    document.getElementById("publishCenter").textContent = "";

    for(var i =0; i < results.length; i++){

    var userPost = results[i];

    //console.log(userPost.get("User") + " / " + userPost.get("Author") + "     / " + userPost.get("Story") + " / " + userPost.get("objectId"));

    var authorTitle = document.createElement("p");
    var newPost = document.createElement("P");
    var title = document.createElement("P");
    var userLabel = document.createElement("p");
    var postId = userPost.id;

    var postBtn = document.createElement("INPUT");
    postBtn.className ="publishBtn";
    postBtn.id ="publishBtn";
    postBtn.setAttribute("Type", "button");
    postBtn.setAttribute("value", "Publish");

    title.textContent = "Story: " + userPost.get("Title");
    authorTitle.textContent = "Author: " + userPost.get("Author");
    newPost.textContent = userPost.get("Story");
    userLabel.textContent = "Published by: " +userPost.get("User").get ("username");

    var postWrapper = document.createElement("DIV");
    postWrapper.className = "postWrapper";
    postWrapper.id = postId;

    document.getElementById("publishCenter").appendChild(postWrapper);
    postWrapper.appendChild(title);
    postWrapper.appendChild(authorTitle);
    postWrapper.appendChild(newPost);
    postWrapper.appendChild(userLabel);
    postWrapper.appendChild(postBtn);

    postBtn.addEventListener("click", publicViewHandler);

    function publicViewHandler(){
    $(this).parent(".postWrapper").clone().appendTo(".storyBoard");


        function testWindow(){
          if($(publicBoard).children().hasClass(".commentWindow")){

          }
          else
          {
            $(".storyBoard").children().append(commentWindow);
          }
        }


      testWindow();
  }



  }
 }
})
```

}

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, jquery hasClass doesn't need '.' prefixing the passed in class name.

https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

Try removing that and see if that get's you anywhere.

Also, where is the variable commentWindow defined? Is it global?

Answer (score 0):

```
var myClone = $(this).parent().clone(true);
          myClone.appendTo(".storyBoard");

          console.log(publicBoard);
          console.log("hello",$(this));

          console.log($(publicBoard).find('.postWrapper').find("commentWindow"));
          myClone.append($(commentWindow).clone());
```

this is what i ended up doing to solve my issue took me a while and a little help from a friend.